# Dynamically adding elements to ArrayList in Groovy

Tags: java, list, arraylist, groovy

I am new to Groovy and, despite reading many articles and questions about this, I am still not clear of what is going on.
From what I understood so far, when you create a new array in Groovy, the underlying type is a Java ArrayList. This means that it should be resizable, you should be able to initialize it as empty and then dynamically add elements through the add method, like so:

```
MyType[] list = []
list.add(new MyType(...))
```

This compiles, however it fails at runtime: No signature of method: [LMyType;.add() is applicable for argument types: (MyType) values: [MyType@383bfa16]

What is the proper way or the proper type to do this?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The Groovy way to do this is

```
def list = []
list << new MyType(...)
```

which creates a list and uses the overloaded [`leftShift`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#leftShift(java.lang.Object)) operator to append an item

See the Groovy [docs on Lists](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_working_with_collections) for lots of examples.

Comment: Ok this works. Actually also list.add(new MyType(...)) works if you define the list like this. But I have a comment and a question. Comment: so there is no way of specifying what type you are going to put in the list when you create it? Question: why does it work in this way and it doesn't if I specify a type? It looks as if it were using a different underlying type then ArrayList in that case.

Comment: You can use `List<MyList> list = []`, but if you're not using `CompileStatic`, it will basically be ignored

Comment: You can also `def list = [new MyType(...)]`

Answer (score 32):

What you actually created with:

```
MyType[] list = []
```

Was fixed size array (not list) with size of 0. You can create fixed size array of size for example 4 with:

```
MyType[] array = new MyType[4]
```

But there's no add method of course.

If you create list with `def` it's something like creating this instance with `Object` (You can read more about `def` [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scoping+and+the+Semantics+of+%22def%22)). And `[]` creates empty `ArrayList` in this case.

So using `def list = []` you can then append new items with `add()` method of `ArrayList`

```
list.add(new MyType())
```

Or more groovy way with overloaded left shift operator:

```
list << new MyType()
```

Comment: Thanks. So is there no way of creating a dynamic list with a specific type?

Comment: The question is already answered by tim_yates in a comment to the second answer :)