# Jenkins pipeline for loop output returning as individual letters rather that items

Tags: for-loop, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline I have a property

```
SERVICES=[test, dev, perf, prod, uat]
```

I want to use this property in a for loop

```
                for(int i=0; i<SERVICES.size(); i++) {
                    println(SERVICES[i])
                }
```

However the for loop is treating the property with each each letter rather that each item so the out put is as follows:

```
[
t
e
s
t
,

d
e
v
...
```

How can I get the get the for loop to treat each item as a whole rather than by letters?

Comment: That "property" is being cast as a string. You need to specify it as an array/list type. Can you update your question with the relevant code where the type would be inferred?

Comment: Splitting the array worked for me, Found the answer here - [how-to-create-and-loop-over-an-arraylist-of-strings-in-jenkins-groovy-pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61146817/how-to-create-and-loop-over-an-arraylist-of-strings-in-jenkins-groovy-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

you are using println which print each item in new line try to print new line outside of a loop

Comment: outside of a loop it returns the whole value "[test, dev, perf, prod, uat]" I want the loop to return each item from the property not each letter

Answer (score 0):

Each string item in the list should be enclosed in single quotes or double quotes

```
SERVICES=['test', 'dev', 'perf', 'prod', 'uat']
```

There is nothing wrong with for loop.